# Developing from a previous version or build using Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build, version

Hi and thanks for your time.

I work with a small development group and we are working on a project using Team Foundation Server on Visual Studio 2010.

We would like to know what we have to use to go back and work with a previous version or build of the project.

Can we use TFS Version Control, TFS Build Server or TFS Source Control ???
How can I do this???

Does this help? --> [tf rollback](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/4ae0b115-a484-406b-bd04-ca390a35205a)
Thank your very much four your help !

Comment: It is best to Branch, Merge or use Rollback Command??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the previous version of a directory for instance, in the Source Control Explorer right click on the directory, then choose "Get specific version..." then select the way you want to choose the version you want to get.

Typically you'll have to come up with a older changeset id then its version will be retrieved locally.

tf rollback is used to "cancel" a given changeset (a changeset is the result of a check-in operation) by creating another one that negate the changes. So it's used when you did a wrong check-in on some files and you want to revert to the previous state.